# Replace value in Pandas DF column, based on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to Python so I apologize in advance for this probably gross code. I'm trying to complete a web scraping project and I currently have a dataframe with a price column (currently as strings). My dilemma is that I would like to iterate over each row, and if the price is displayed as weekly (contains pw) then I would like to update the price to monthly; i.e multiply it by 4. For the rows where the price is already monthly, I want to do nothing.

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({"prices":["350pw", "1000pm", "600pw", "1000pm", "1000pm"], "Column2":["H", "E", "L", "P", "!"]})
```

which generates:

```
    prices Column2
0    350pw       H
1   1000pm       E
2    600pw       L
3   1000pm       P
4   1000pm       !
```

I'm able to find the rows and extract just the numbers. From there I converted to int, multiplied by 4 but am not able to use the replace function with ints.

```
for x in mydf[mydf['prices'].str.contains('pw')]['prices']:
    weekly_price = int(x[0:3])
    monthly_price_int = weekly_price * 4
```

Not sure where to go from here....

The end result would be:

```
    prices Column2
0   1400pw       H
1   1000pm       E
2   2400pw       L
3   1000pm       P
4   1000pm       !
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a pandas question, but this is how you probably should go about doing this:

```
import pandas as pd

mydf = [your df above]

#define a function to convert from weekly to monthly
def make_monthly(cell):
    if 'pw' in cell:
        weekly_price = int(cell[0:3])
        monthly_price_int = weekly_price * 4
        new_cell = str(monthly_price_int)+'pm' #you need to update the period designation as well
        return new_cell
    else:
        return cell
```

Finally, modify the values in the 'prices' row, where necessary:

```
mydf['prices'] = mydf['prices'].map(make_monthly)
```

Output:

```
   prices   Column2
0   1400pm  H
1   1000pm  E
2   2400pm  L
3   1000pm  P
4   1000pm  !
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
def preprocess(x):
    if(x['position']>=0):
        x['prices']=str(int(x['prices'][:x['position']])*4)+"pm"
        return x
    return x

mydf = pd.DataFrame({"prices":["350pw", "1000pm", "600pw", "1000pm", "1000pm"], "Column2":["H", "E", "L", "P", "!"]})
mydf["position"]=mydf.prices.str.find('pw')
mydf=mydf.apply(preprocess, axis=1)
mydf.drop(['position'],axis=1,inplace=True)

print(mydf)
```

[image]